# How do I send POST in place of PUT or DELETE in Ember?

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

How does one update or delete a record using the POST verb using the Ember RESTAdapter? By default it sends the json using PUT or DELETE verbs. Sending using these verbs is blocked for where I'm working at.

I was kind of hoping I could do the Rails thing where you send a POST and tell it whether it's secretly a PUT or DELETE using extra meta information.

I'm working with Ember 1.0.0 and ember-data 1.0.0beta2 through the RESTAdapter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that overriding the `DS.RESTAdapter` `updateRecord` and `deleteRecord` could work:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record);

    var id = Ember.get(record, 'id');

    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, id), "POST", { data: data });
  },
  deleteRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var id = Ember.get(record, 'id');

    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, id), "POST");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Although your answer set my on the right path, in the end I ended up having to override Embers ajax wrapper instead (this.ajax() in the code sample) rather than updateRecord() or deleteRecord() so that I could add the form attribute {_method='PUT'}" with a content type that Rails would accept. But I didn't explicitly specify that the answer had to be Rails friendly so Accepted Answer goes to you sir!

Comment: You are welcome. Rails use the _method="PUT", because the form in browsers don't support the PUT. In ajax calls all will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can override ajaxOptions on RESTAdapter:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    ajaxOptions: function(url, type, hash) {
        hash = hash || {};

        if (type === 'PUT' || type === 'DELETE') {
            hash.data = hash.data || {};
            hash.data['_method'] = type;
            type = 'POST';
        }

        return this._super(url, type, hash);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax for ***Ember 2.7.3*** and ***Ember Data 2.7.0***

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  updateRecord: function(store, type, snapshot) {
    let id = snapshot.id;
    let data = this.serialize(snapshot, { includeId: true });
    const urlForQueryRecord = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'updateRecord');

    return this.ajax(urlForQueryRecord, 'POST', { data: data });
  }
})
```

Please notice the change of `type.typeKey` to `type.modelName`